# Static Method Memory Allocation

Tags: java, static, static-methods, static-members

We have two classifications heap and stack . When a object is created, memory for object is stored in heap. What if the class has static methods ,which can be called using class name. If  object is not created then how will it allocate memory and if it does where will it allocate memory?

Comment: And what is this allocated memory meant to be for?

Comment: It's clear from his comment below that it's Java, so I've added a Java tag.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the JVM, but static fields are usually stored in a special object on the heap. (You can see it in a heap dump) When the ClassLoader is unloaded, its classes and their static "objects"/fields are also cleaned up.

The only thing different about the static "object" is you can't get a reference to it. (But you can use reflection to access the fields)

Answer (score 1):

Methods (i.e., code) aren't stored in an object; all objects of a class will share the code for a method. Regardless of language (Java, C++, or virtually anything else) there will be only a single copy of the code for any method, static or not. Generally there's a specific area of memory -- i.e., a CODE segment in a native language like C++, or a special heap area in Java -- where code is loaded.

Comment: OK memory for objects is created along with class. i.e only memory for class is created in heap (java) Only when we use new operator we can create memory. But for classes like Math we cant instantiate ..in that case where is the memory created?

Comment: As I said (but I'm not sure you understood), code isn't stored in the objects, so this is not a problem at all. It is not stored anywhere where you can get to it, in fact. It's stored elsewhere in a special part of the heap. The JVM loads the bytecode from a class file, transforms it in some implementation dependent way, and makes the methods available to your program.

Comment: @user980918 java.lang.Math does not need much memory on runtime - the only piece I can think about is the static variable which holds a `Random` object. Static variables for a class are stored in the heap, together with the `Class` object. (Local variables in methods are in the stack, independent of static-ness of the method.)

Answer (score -1):

- Permanent Generation(PermGen) space of heap contain permanent class
  metadata and descriptors information.
- PermGen space always reserved for classes and those that are tied to
  the classes(Static members, static functions, etc...)
- Static function belongs to the class so they can be called to without
  creating the object of the class.