# When is memory created for static methods in Java

Tags: java, memory-management

I have two classes A and B. Class A has main method and class B has two methods namely, `Add` and `Sub`.

My question is, when is the memory allocated for class B?

At Line no. 2 or 8; when I import the class or when I call the class?

If the memory is allocated at line no. 2. At line no. 3 I have imported java.util.* so object will be allocated for all the class in util package.

If the memory is allocated at line no. 8 then what about the sub method?

**Class A**

```
   1 package sample;
   2 import sample1.B;
   3 import java.util.*;
   4 public class A 
   5 {
   6    public static void main(String args[])
   7    {
   8        B.Add(3, 3);
   9    }
   10 }
```

**Class B**

```
package sample1;
public class B 
{
    public static int Add(int A,int B)
    {
        return A+B;
    }
    public static int sub(int A,int B)
    {
        return A-B;
    }
}
```

Comment: this stack overflow link may also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673359/static-method-memory-allocation

Answer (score 5):

Line two is not code that translates into JVM bytecode instructions. It's merely a declaration to the compiler to help it resolve simple names.

Immediately *before* line eight is the *latest* possible moment when the `ClassLoader` for `B` will run and the static initializers (if any) for `B` will run. Execution of the `ClassLoader` for `B`, however, *could* occur earlier. The [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) merely guarantees that a `Class` object will be loaded once and only once and not later than before its first use and that the static initializers will run once and only once and *immediately* before the first moment where they are needed.

> At line no 3 i have imported java.util.* so object will be allocated for all the class in util package.

No, again, an `import` declaration does *not* translate into JVM bytecode instructions. It does not cause any objects to be created or loaded at runtime. It is *only* a declaration that the compiler uses to resolve simple names. This is so you can say `Set` instead of `java.util.Set`.

> If the memory is allocated at line no 8 then what about the `sub` method?

The `ClassLoader` for `B` and the static initializers for `B` will run *before* line eight is executed, and they will *not* be run again if you invoke any additional static members of class `B`.

Comment: thank you very much for your replay!!!! i have another question if class object will be created at line no 8 mean why my constructor is not invoked !!!!

Comment: What constructor? `A` and `B` both have default public no-argument instance constructors, but you never created any instances of `A` nor `B` so they will never run.

Comment: If they will not run again mean the memory is allocated for both the methods at line n 8 fine. If i have 20 static methods in my class and i want to use only one method the what happens.

Comment: @alagusathish: The `Class` object for `B` is loaded and its static initializers are run if you use one static method, or twenty static methods. It doesn't matter.

Comment: @alagusathish  [Do not forget to mark it as answer,If it's helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)..And every where you are writing `replay`  its `reply`

Comment: You have conflated class loading with class initialization. Class initialization is guaranteed to happen at a very precise moment: upon the first use of the class. It is only class *loading* which has the freedom that you describe. For a quite poignant proof look up Josh Bloch's *Lazy initialization holder class idiom*.

Answer (score 1):

Memory (for statics and assorted control info) is allocated for a *class* when the class is loaded.

Memory is allocated for an *instance* when the instance is created (ie, `new`).

Memory is allocated for a *method* when the method is invoked.  (And it doesn't matter whether the method is a static or instance method.)